# online map of 242,888 locations: which service to use? (what if temporal heat map?)

Tags: google-maps, carto, arcgis-online, spatio-temporal-data

I have a 161.8 MB large CSV file with geocoded locations (with latitude and longitude) for 242,888 lines. I want to have an embeddable online map of all this. I wonder which service could deal with this amount of data, and what you'd recommend.

Relevant details:

— if the data looks too big (162 MB), I can cut down on fields, some are extraneous. But others would be nice to link to the points on the map, even if they are not strictly there for the mapping. (So people could navigate back to the original data source, e.g.)

— I have date field for a temporal map. It would be great to use this to let viewers filter which points to show, or even better, show animated versions if possible.

— one field would be good to use for showing intensity, hot spots on the map (viz. concentration of procurement contracts in space and time)

— the data is the universe of procurement contracts in Hungary since 1998. So good Unicode support is a must, as is global coverage (though I think both are pretty standard these days).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CartoDB can definitely handle a dataset that large, including filtering, infowindows, and multiple different versions of the map (i.e. styles and selected filters) using the same dataset.

This, for example, is around 100mb of polygon data being styled on the fly with each click of the little menu,

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/raw/8324313/

[image: dynamic style]

You can find a lot more information and resources over here, http://developers.cartodb.com/